# Info area on all screens

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1

Is there any solution known to display the info area, meaning the small 16x16 icons inclusive the clock, on all screens and not just on the default screen?

Comment: Do you mean the whole taskbar, or just the notification area?

Comment: Just the notification area. On windows 8, the whole taskbar is displayed on all screens by default.